# Mystery processes maxing CPU Usage

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, task-manager

I have recently re-installed Windows 7 following a BSOD incident and I have noticed the CPU usage maxing out occasionally when I am not doing very much (not when it has recently started up). When I hear the fans going full throttle I check task manager to see what is working the computer so hard, but nothing is listed that is using more than a few % CPU, yet the overall usage is 100% (or high ninties) e.g.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get the the bottom of what the computer is really doing when this happens?

Comment: You'll probably need to click the button that says "Show processes from all users". That should show you the offending process, at least.

Comment: What was the reason for your previous BSOD, do you have an error code? They could be related

Comment: @ekaj Sorry, I don't have the code from the BSOD, Windows crashed when I was scanning for devices (attempting to tether my laptop to my phone for a 3G connection). It crashed and would not boot into windows, so I did a re-install.

Comment: run xperf when you have the CPU issue again and provide the zipped ETL file: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Answer (score 0):

You could try to go to the performance tab and then click on resource monitor. Go to the CPU tab and leave it on for a few minutes and you should have your culprit.